# Streams versus collections

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of players and want to get the player with the min rating. I could do:

```
Player player1 = Collections.min(players,Comparator.comparing(Player::getRating));
```

Or I could do:

```
Player player2 = players.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Player::getRating)).get();
```

What's better in terms of performance or anything else?

Comment: do a benchmark and see.

Comment: There is no magic involved. Both methods iterate over all elements and compare.

Comment: @Holger what if the stream could theoretically register that it is already sorted by a  certain property, like `TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing)`, etc. only theoretically

Comment: @Aomine you removed the `é`? anyway, I think that theoretically if the steam is sorted and that is a flag registered on the stream pipeline, you could simply return the first or the last entry without traversing the source

Comment: I was thinking about it for a while now and eventually decided to simplify things and keep it as `e` instead of `é`.

Comment: @Aomine well that was "your thing" IMO, but well...

Comment: @Eugene in theory, it could, in practice, it doesn’t. So if `players` is a `TreeSet` with the right order, you’d better ask it for the minimum directly…

Answer (score 3):

It should not make a great difference.
We could argue that the stream way could take advantage of the parallel stream option while `Collections.min()` could not.
And in both cases you present, the boxing may have a cost with a big list. So you should favor `comparingInt()`/`comparingDouble()`/`comparingLong()` to `comparing()`.

Comment: The stream variant also provides you with more options in terms of what to do in the "no value" case as the call upon `min` returns an `Optional<T>`. whereas the `Collections.min` would simply throw an exception if the collection is empty.

Comment: @Eugene It is indeed an interesting point for already sorted things.

Comment: @Aomine It is a interesting point but in real applications I will favor the one or the second according to the context. Sometimes you are looking for the fault tolerance because what you manipulate requires that. In other context, you don't want this tolerance because functionally it has not to be accepted.  So using something as `Optional` and handle cases that cannot happen can so appear as dead code or "surprising" code by people that read the code.

Answer (score 3):

Given your question is "What's better in terms of performance *or anything else*?" 
@davidxxx and @Eugene have already elaborated on some interesting points, here's another one:

Another reason to favour the stream variant is that the call upon `min` returns an `Optional<T>` which itself is descriptive enough and also enables the user to decide what to do in the "no value" case whereas the `Collections.min` would simply throw an exception if the collection is empty, which may as well be what the user wants but it's something to take into consideration. My personal preference would be the stream version simply because it provides you more options in terms of what to do in the "no value" case.

That said if you don't need those additional options simply because there will *always* be a min value or an exception is meaningful enough then I'd go with the first approach.

Ultimately, what option you decide to proceed with should not depend on performance because there's not a huge difference in between them unless otherwise, you believe you can leverage the parallel stream API.

Rather, in this specific case, I'd suggest you take into consideration what I've mentioned above and go with the more readable/comfortable approach to you and/or your colleagues.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the incoming source is already *sorted*, the Stream implementation could potentially just return the first (or last) entry from that source, without traversing the entire `Collection` unlike `Collections.min`. For your example that seems way too complicated to do probably, but for a simpler one things would be easier may be.

This is not done at the moment, but could be implemented in the future, as such I *could* favor the `stream` one probably.

Comment: +1. Also, another reason to favour the stream variant is that the call upon `min` returns an `Optional<T>` which itself is descriptive enough and also enables the user to decide what to do in the "no value" case whereas the `Collections.min` would simply throw an exception if the collection is empty, which may as well be what the user wants but it's something to take into consideration. My personal preference would be the stream version simply because it provides you more options in terms of what to do in the "no value" case.